# Поменять значение Input при выборе select

Tags: jquery, input

Всем привет есть такой `input`:

```
 <input type='hidden' name='oa' value=''>
```

Есть такой select

```
<select>
    <option value="15">15$ - 1 месяц</option>
    <option value="1">1$ - 1 день</option>
    <option value="4">4$ - 5 дней</option>
    <option value="7">7$ - 10 дней</option>
</select>
```

Как при выборе определенного `select` подставлялось значение в `input` посредством jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно следующим способом (для удобства добавил `id` селекту и поменял тип инпута с `hidden` на `text`):

```js
$("#select").change(function(e) {
  $("input[name='oa']").val(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' name='oa' value=''>
<select id='select'>
  <option value="15">15$ - 1 месяц</option>
  <option value="1">1$ - 1 день</option>
  <option value="4">4$ - 5 дней</option>
  <option value="7">7$ - 10 дней</option>
</select>
```

Немного поясню: `$("#select").change(function(e) {...})` - сработает на изменении селекта. Для ознакомления почитать можно тут: [jQuery `.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Строка кода: `$("input[name='oa']")` - получить элемент содержащий атрибут имени со значением `oa`. Для ознакомления почитать можно тут: [jQuery: Attribute Contains Selector `[name*=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Меняем значение у инпута с помощью `.val(e.target.value);`. Для ознакомления почитать можно тут: [jQuery: `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Не мудрить и просто сделать:

```
<select name='oa'>
    <option value="15">15$ - 1 месяц</option>
    <option value="1">1$ - 1 день</option>
    <option value="4">4$ - 5 дней</option>
    <option value="7">7$ - 10 дней</option>
</select>
```